# SharePoint 2010 Clean up

Tags: 2010, master-page

I'm in the process of cleaning up a client's SharePoint 2010 master page and per recommendations is trying to add `xml:lang="en"` to the `html-tag`, however, during render I find it stripped out.

I have `XhtmlConformance="Strict"` which should in theory tell SP to render the output to the strict validation, but this has no effect either.

Google is useless, unless I'm looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: Is the user you are editing the masterpage with the same as the one you are viewing the site with? Are you sure that you have checked in the latest changes for the masterpage?

Comment: @DanielZiga apparently SharePoint 2010's rendering strips out the xml:lang="en" by default. now way around it as far as I can see, except intercepting the render (HttpModule) and adding it back in. too much of a hassle.